# Creating a grid of Canvases without gaps in tkinter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have the following code that generates a grid of canvases but there are spaces between each

```
from tkinter import *

grid = []

master = Tk()

for n in range(0,10):
    grid.append([])
    for i in range(0,10):
        grid[n].append(Canvas(master, bg="#222", height="20", width="20"))
        grid[n][i].grid(row=n, column=i)
```

How would I remove these so that it looks like one big canvas?

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the image of your output?

Comment: Your first step should be to read documentation on the canvas object, and experiment with the options such as borderwidth and highlightthickness, to name a couple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(...)
canvas['highlightthickness'] = 0
```

or specifically:

```
grid[-1][-1]['highlighthickness'] = 0
```